# Xamarin Forms 4.1: ScrollView scroll is covering header view in android device 9.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, scroll, scrollview

In Xamarin Forms 4.1, When scroll, scrollview content is covering/overflow the headerview and scrollview content is not shown completely.

Tried with **IsClippedToBounds** to true.
Created scrollviewrenderer, OnDraw() -> set clip to bound property. But didn't worked.

**Example: Here is the XAML design**

```
 <Stacklayout>
      <HeaderView/>
      <ScrollView IsClippedToBounds="true">
          <Stacklayout>
                <label text="1"/>
                 ........
                 ........
                <label text="100"/>
          </Stacklayout>
      </ScrollView>
</Stacklayout>
```

Comment: Please help me!! Thanks in advance

Comment: what HeaderView contains?

Comment: Your question is a tad bit vague can you be specific?

Comment: It is working with Xamarin Forms 3.1 version but not with 4.1

Comment: HeaderView is ContentView holds Title label and buttons

Comment: Is this headerView in your ScrollView itself? Or is it outside?

Comment: HeaderView is Outside the scrollView

Comment: Then how do you expect it to scroll if it is out of it?

Comment: That is the issue Im facing, even when the HeaderView is outside the ScrollView, the scroll covers the HeaderView meaning if user scrolls down, content of scrollView is overflowing on HeaderView

Comment: That is the issue Im facing, even when the HeaderView is outside the ScrollView, the scroll covers the HeaderView meaning if user scrolls down, content of scrollView is overflowing on HeaderView

Comment: Always I need to have HeaderView visible, but currently it is not

Comment: @ChaitanyaDwarapudi I could not reproduce the HeaderView, could you provide the code sample?

Comment: HeaderView is just a contentView with title label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make a custom control as the headerview in your description. And test on Xamarin.forms 4.1, works well.

**MyCustomConrol:**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="Aqua">
    <Label x:Name="Title_label" Text="Title" TextColor="Black" FontSize="25"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnHello" Text="Hello" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="4,0,8,0"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:MyCustomControl></local:MyCustomControl>
    <!--<HeaderView/>-->
    <ScrollView IsClippedToBounds="true">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="1"/>
            <Label Text="2"/>
            <Label Text="3"/>
               ……………
               …………………
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

**Result:**

[image]

You could download from ScrollView/XamarinDemo folder of GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Answer (score 0):

If you want your header to be always visible then rather than placinf your content in Header, it will be better to place your header content first then below that place your listview. Thus, your header remains intact and listview scrolls.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. But we using scrollView not ListView.